# Python sqlite3 tkinter. Run query, add column and save to xlsx

Tags: python, sql, excel, sqlite, tkinter

I got some question. I would like to create an app to run some sql query(ill use sqlite3) and then show data with tkinter, but ill like to add 1 more column to the results where user can input some data and next save it to the xlsx. What is the problem? I can't figure out method to add that column for user input. I'll show query results as a data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better if you provide minimum reproducible example. You can create Entry widget to add extra column to tkinter. Get the data from .get() method and add it to sqlite database using Update. Then you can read whole database as pandas dataframe and export is to excel using to_excel method.